# H bridge Inverting Wave issue sound from gate driver

Tags: h-bridge

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to drive H bridge using the following configuration
I am producing an inverting.

4 * N channel mosfets Fdd8447
gate driver ic TC4428 (used alternatively IX4428 and IXDF604 but no avail)
Frequency stays <15Hz
Power rating remains within half a watt
At the Output I have
2.2K Ohm resistor
1Uf capacitor

I am not using IR2110 since I cannot produce the required +10V on high side gate as my  max output amplitude stays within 20V.
I am able to produce the required wave but I get wave this after applying the capacitor... otherwise worst...after adding the capacitor there is unusual sound in the gate driver as well...in fact I have even burnt one. Whats the problem?  [image]

New picture [image]

Furthermore my load is not motor but a small and a capacitive one like the human skin

Comment: Is that a polarized capacitor at H bridge output?

Comment: That looks like a low side FET driver with no bootstrapping circuit (?) If so, those top N-channel MOSFET'S can't be driven properly.

Comment: No I have used 1uf non polar capacitor the schematic is misleading

Comment: If I use high side driver as well how can i generate the additional volatge usually +10V when the output I want is ranged 5V to 20V wave

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. What is your supply voltage? Do you want a 5V to 20V square-wave across the load? That implies you want a voltage drop across your switch transistors in which case there is little reason to bother with MOSFETS.

Comment: My supply voltage is 3.6 to 4.2 volts which I have boosted. I want a square wave within 5V to 20V. Just using the high side driver I will need to for e.g. at ir2110 high side floating offset voltage+10V to get high side absolute voltage. This means when I am boosting battery to suppose 8v(VDD /boost in diagram labels) to get slightly less than 8V at the output I wont be able to run the high side mosfets as the high side floating supply requires something above 10volts?

Answer (score 1):

> At the Output I have 2.2K Ohm resistor 1Uf capacitor

Using a polarized capacitor here results in major problems, as the capacitor can break through if the voltage is applied negatively. In that situation the current through the capacitor is not limited and also the/both MOSFET break through too.

(Addiionally, please provide the same values in the schematics as in the text. 100 pF is usually not polarazed, but usually 1 µF).

Also the ratings of the capacitor are important. With an unlimited 1 µF at the outputs at the bridge, and C has a low ESR, the inrush current through the capacitor is very high!

Comment: I have used 1uf non polar smd capacitor. Any values given in schematic should not be followed